# How do Flags work for higher rep users?

Tags: support, flags

With the current moderator elections, I noticed a lot of candidates reporting their *helpful flags* count.  I decided to take a look at my own flags statistics and noticed that most of them were fairly old, I'm guessing before I reached 3k rep, when I had to use flags as a way to close questions or mark them as duplicates, whereas now, I can just vote on closing them directly.

My question is, does that mean >3k rep users don't get *helpful flags* for marking things as duplicate or closing questions?

EDIT:

If that is the case, it seems like there is some asymmetry between how <3k and >3k users accumulate flags.  Is that intended?

How do >3k users have such high flag counts? Are they all spam/offensive/mod flags?

Comment: No they don't. They just use one of their close votes.

Comment: You do get helpful flags if you flag content in a manner that a moderator deems helpful though.

Comment: NAA/VLQ flags on answers. Some >3k users spend 100/day on that.

Comment: Re: your edit, flags can be accumulated in a number of ways. Mostly through janitorial and community level moderation work. If you review a lot of questions, you tend to see a lot of flaggable content, and you accumulate a lot of helpful flags. There are even bots that attempt to identify flaggable content as soon as it reaches the site, then posts in chatrooms for regular users to review and flag if necessary.

Comment: Once you gain rep, you just no longer have to ask somebody else to take care of it, you do it yourself.  Mod candidates tend to be a bit slow at gaining rep, perhaps.  Different talents.

Comment: As you've got 10k, you can use the [10k tools](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) page directly.

Comment: Somewhat related on [MSE - I don't flag - What is wrong with me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172072/i-dont-flag-what-is-wrong-with-me)

Answer (score 14):

Close flags are but one type of flag. In fact, I don't think they existed back when I started flagging things as a normal user. For most people who have cast a large number of flags, close flags are a small percentage of their total. I had thousands of flags before I was elected, none of them close flags.

There are plenty of non-answers, spam posts, voting rings, sock puppets, and other extraordinary items that you can use flags to inform moderators about. One of the reasons people emphasize flags when talking about moderator candidates is this is what moderators do: handle flags for items that the community couldn't otherwise deal with.

It's important that a moderator candidate know what flags should be used for, and to recognize content that moderators should know about. Also, if someone is regularly finding content that moderators should act on, maybe they should be given a chance to deal with it directly. In my experience, the best moderators we've had are the people I saw time and again casting useful flags to bring items to our attention.

Answer (score 2):

For the second question:

- I wasn't getting reputation very quickly before I was 3K, and that gave me time to accumulate flags.
- NaA and VLQ flags are still the only report channel for their respective problems, up until 20K.
- The "Requires ♦ Moderator Attention" flag can be used on *any* post. Yes, **any**. Including deleted posts.
- Comment flags.