# Can >3k users flag for closure if they are out of close votes?

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close

In [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338237/6471538) answer from 2016, Stephen Leppik mentions that:

> After 3K, you can still raise close flags. For example, if you've exhausted all of your close votes. (If you do have remaining close votes, selecting "Should be Closed…" just brings up the vote-to-close dialogue.)

I tried to do this recently. I was out of close votes for the day on the main site, but still had plenty of flags. I opened the flag dialog on the question and selected a close reason, but the system would not let me submit the dialog, claiming that I had 0 close votes remaining.

Can users with more than 3,000 rep raise close *flags* if they are *out* of close *votes*? If so, what is the procedure for doing so? If not, is Stephen's answer *incorrect* (as of the date it was written) or is it *obsolete* (in the sense that the ability for 3K users to raise close flags has been removed)?

Comment: In short - no they can't. At 3k they're always translated to a vote and if you don't have any left to use - you can't do it.

Comment: His answer is wrong. The system has *never* worked that way.

Comment: Under 'What happens when a question gets flags or close votes?' [If a user with close vote privileges uses the flag dialog to flag to close a question, the system automatically knows these are close votes not flags - a user would technically be voting to close not flagging to close.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/164200)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way, but I think it would be a good idea.

Comment: I guess when you're out of close votes, you've got to revert back from reviewing to asking and answering ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yeah, that answer was wrong, and thanks for calling me out on it. I've updated it now.

I think sorta heard that factoid at some point, didn't bother to question it, and regurgitated it later without any references at all. I didn't *have* any way to verify it for myself since I wasn't 3K at the time.

I actually have run into this block before, but by that time I had forgotten about it. This was a good reminder.