# "Duplicate" and "Needs Improvement" showing under flags, even though I can vote normally for the same offenses

Tags: bug, flags

I went to flag a question as spam, and I'm seeing options to flag as a duplicate and that it needs improvement.
[image]

I may be crazy, but as a high(ish)-rep user I don't recall those options being there last time I flagged a post. I have enough rep to vote to close a question as duplicate and needs clarity/focus, and I thought once that was the case, the options were removed from the flagging dialog.

Are those options supposed to be shown to higher-rep users who can vote?

Comment: That's weird I too remember the "duplicate" flag being removed at some time from the flag options (Was present at the start when I got close votes privilege, but later got removed), Just yesterday I didn't see "duplicate" as one of the options when flagging.

Comment: *"I may be crazy, but as a high(ish)-rep user I don't recall those options being there last time I flagged a post."* - I'm afraid you may indeed be crazy. IIRC, they have always been there even with close privileges, but using them does just use a close vote anyway. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269743/flag-question-vs-close-vote-vs-both

Comment: @41686d6564 IIRC, no, you can't flag for closure after you've run out of close votes, the close privilege permanently makes it so close flags are attempted to be converted to close votes and close flagging itself isn't possible

Comment: @cigien No, that's referring to both options under the flagging dialog, this is a different question

Comment: I feel that perhaps the point of this question is being missed? I clearly remember at the start when I got the close votes privilege the flag option for duplicate was there. Later on since quite some time the duplicate flag option was _not present_ (ergo that option was not there in the list) for me, in fact just yesterday I remember it not being there. So this question is potentially about a feature that was added and then potentially removed today?

Comment: @Nick You're right. Looks like [I'm not the only one who was led to believe that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360302/8967612).

Comment: @Nick Oops, that's not the right target. Hopefully a gold tag badge holder will see the question, and edit the target list.

Comment: @cigien I mean, they're pretty similar, as opening the extended flagging menu after unlocking close votes does just open the close vote menu :p

Comment: @Nick Yeah, I guess. It's not an exact dupe, but probably close enough that it's fine to leave on the target list.

Comment: Huh. Weird that I was somehow blind to that then suddenly noticed today. Well, thanks guys. Sorry.

Comment: It is removed again from the flag options... See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x9mo.jpg)

Comment: @Abdul I knew it! That's what I'm used to seeing. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Carcigenicate if you edit the question and remove the part about the use of both being present and focus on the addition / removal of this feature I will cast a reopen vote for it. :)

Comment: Solved the mystery, it looks like according to the _close votes_ cast and other things done on a post (upvotes, etc.) the "duplicate", "needs improvement" and "very low quality" options might not be shown in the flag menu. Related: [Where is the very low quality flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286971/14991864) and [Where is Low Quality flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374977/14991864)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Updated, and thanks. That answers my question.